# How to populate select field from View result like in

Tags: 8, forms

In a custom content entity, I have defined this field

```
$fields['from_seliste_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Offreur'))
  ->setDescription(t('Le SÉListe qui a rendu le service (qui reçoit les graines)'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'person')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'views')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', [
    'view' => [
      'view_name' => 'sel_selistes',
      'display_name' => 'entity_reference_1',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'weight' => $weight,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'weight' => $weight,
    'type' => 'options_select',
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setRequired(TRUE);
```

In the corresponding form, the field appears as wanted as a dropdown list populated with the result of the View `sel_selistes`:
[image]

I'd like to create another form with the same functionality.
How should I code the field in the form?

```
$form['mySelectField'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => [], <-- ??????
  '#title' => $this
    ->t('whatever'),
);
```

Comment: `I'd like to create another form with the same functionality` copy paste? or you  mean on a non entity form?

Comment: on a non entity form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to provide an exact answer, but something along these lines.

```
// Programmatically execute view
$view = views_get_view('sel_selistes'); //  view machine name
$view->set_display("entity_reference_1"); // view display name
// $view->set_arguments($arg) // looks like you don't have arguments.
$view->execute();

$view_results = []; // create array
// loop through results
foreach ($view->result as $row_id => $row) {
  // some php magic so you add to array like this $view_results[$nid_value] = $some_field_row_value;
}

$form['my_select_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#options' => $view_results,
  '#title' => $this
    ->t('whatever'),
);
```